# Is this the right format for String format in java comparing from Objective C?

Tags: java, android, objective-c

I am converting a code from Objective C to java for Android and I can't find an equivalence to this line of code.

In Objective C I have this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000]
```

In java I am trying to do this:

```
String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.0f", System.currentTimeMillis())
```

but I get a warning from Android studio that says:

> Argument type 'long' does not match the type of the format specifier
>   '%.0f'

Is there anything that Im doing wrong?

Can I ignore this warning and the line will still work? or I need another format String?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it work? If so, you could add a cast to eliminate the warning like `String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.0f", (double) System.currentTimeMillis())`

Comment: use "`%d`" instead of "`%.0f`"

Comment: Can u try String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) ? Anyway it won't give any decimal value so. You can directly use that value right? If locale is your constraint I'll update my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the android javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html), the `%.0f` means "format this floating point number with at least one decimal place", but you're passing in the result of `System.currentTimeMillis()`, which is of type `long` (an integer type), which explains the warning.

Changing the `%0.f` to `%d` will get rid of the warning.